# Is it possible to maintain content showing by jquery event if user refresh page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my web page, I changed content (like gmail) by clicking navigation menu by using jquery. Here is the example,

```
    <p>
    I have a classifieds website, and on the page where ads are showed, 
    I am creating a "Send a tip to a friend" form... So anybody who wants can send a tip of the ad to some friends email-adress. 
    I am guessing the form must be submitted to a php page right? When submitting the form, the page gets reloaded... I don't want that... Is there any way to make it not reload and still send the mail? Preferrably without ajax or jquery... Thanks
    </p>
    <button id="chg">
    Change content
    </button>
```

Here is what I tried with jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var isnew = "";
    console.log(isnew);
        if(isnew == true) {
            console.log("check "+isnew);
            $("p").html("New contents are here........");
        }

    $("#chg").click(function(){
        isnew = true;
        console.log(isnew);
        $("p").html("New contents are here........");
    });
});
```

The main point what I want is, after I click `change content` button, now the text in `p` element is changed to `New contents are here.....`.

At this time, if user reload the page, I want to show just only changed content like `New contents are here.....`. Not the text(paragrah) that are written in `html`.

I already tried as much as I can. But I can't solve the problem. So, I'm very appreciate for any suggestion.

Comment: You can try [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: @anu Can you please make your comment to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("newContent")) {
     // Restore the contents
     $("p").html(sessionStorage.getItem("newContent"));
    }
    $("#chg").click(function(){
        var newCont = "New contents are here........";
        $("p").html(newCont);
        sessionStorage.setItem("newContent", newCont);
    });
});
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

[check usage](http://caniuse.com/#search=sessionStorage)